# Save image depending on which panel is topmost

Tags: c#, image, graph, charts, save

I am making an interface where on the left is a column of menu buttons.
A couple of the buttons bring different graphs (each on it's own panel) to the front to view, using the BringToFront() method. I also have a "Save image" button where you can save the graph.

How do I setup the button to save whichever panel is in the front? Is it better practice to use "Enable/Disable" instead of BringToFront and then save whichever panel is enabled?

Previously, I had all these panels within a TabControl, and I had the button save the graph on whichever tab was selected, but I got rid of the tabs because I did not like the way it looked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most easiest way is to store the actual active image in a variable, changing it's value by clicking the buttons. If you store the image itself or just the index or whatever to determine which image is actually infront is on your choice.

Another aproach could be, show and hide your panels, then you can iterate over your panel list and check which panel is not hidden.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the changing variable sounds like a good idea. 

Would it look something like...

var imageIndex = 0;

//..code to change index depending on which button was selected on the left side

if (imageIndex == 1)
  save chart #1

else if (imageIndex == 2)
  save chart #2

etc.

Comment: that's exactly what i meant

Comment: It worked, perfectly. Thank you so much. I would Upvote it, but apparently I'm still too new.

Comment: glad i can help